# How to create a dataframe from dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, xml.etree

I'm a unexperienced programmer (python) and I'm trying to get my head arround the following:

I'm want to parse an xml file that looks like this (modified from original):

```
<traceData dataFrames="1" equip="ZZXX55_03_06">
    <dataFrame>
        <rec time="0.000000" f1="0.17773" f2="688.00006" f3="688.02917"/>
        <rec time="0.002000" f1="0.17773" f2="688.00006" f3="688.02917"/>
        <rec time="0.004000" f1="0.17432" f2="688.00000" f3="688.02917"/>
        <rec time="0.006000" f1="0.17432" f2="688.00000" f3="688.02917"/>
        <rec time="0.008000" f1="0.17432" f2="687.99988" f3="688.02917"/>
    </dataFrame>
</traceData>
```

So the xml file contains a block with time series data. I want to stuff this timeseries data into a (pandas) dataframe so that it eventually looks like this:

```
    time        f1          f2          f3
0   0.000000    0.17773     688.00006   688.02917
1   0.002000    0.17773     688.00006   688.02917
2   0.004000    0.17432     688.00000   688.02917
3   0.006000    0.00000     688.00000   688.02917
4   0.008000    0.17773     687.99988   688.02917
```

My code to parse the data from the xml file looks like this (partial from original):

```
.......
        xml_data = object.get()["Body"].read().decode("utf-8")
        tree = ElementTree(fromstring(xml_data))
        root = tree.getroot()
        for elem in root:
            if elem.tag == 'dataFrame':
                for rec in elem:
                    time=rec.attrib.get('time') 
                    f1=rec.attrib.get('f1')
                    f2=rec.attrib.get('f2')
                    f3=rec.attrib.get('f3')
                    Dictionary = { 'time':str(time) ,'f1':str(f1),'f2':str(f2),'f3':str(f3) }
                    print(Dictionary)
```

My plan was to first put all data into dictionaries and then loop-append all rows into on big dictionary and from there stuff it into a dataframe. As I was struggling with stuffing all the individual dictionaries into a single big dictionary, I thought..... no!.... There must be an easier way to create the dataframe as indicated above.

Who can help me? I'm very curious...

Thanks in advance.

D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can form a list of dictionaries like [{'time':0.00000,'f1':1.00,'f2':000},{'time':0.00000,'f1':1.00,'f2':000},.....]

and the pass this list of dict to pandas Data-frame for creating a data frame

```
data= [{'time':0.00000,'f1':1.00,'f2':000},{'time':0.00000,'f1':1.00,'f2':000},.....]

pd.DataFrame(data)
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

pd is pandas object

this will result in data frame in the format what you expect